# What's the difference between overwriting `intrinsicContentSize` and giving that object constraints that express the same size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Aside from the literal implementation differences, how do the two approaches differ conceptually?  Why would you favor one over the other? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intrinsic content size is a function whose value changes based on (wait for it)... the content! You should use it only if this is that kind of view. The canonical example is a UILabel or a UIButton, whose size is based on the text it contains (among other things), or a UIImageView, whose size is based on the image it contains.

Absolute size constraints, on the other hand, are absolute. They impose a size based on external considerations.

We can sum up by saying that the intrinsic content size sizes this view *from the inside out*, whereas constraints size the view *from the outside in*.